# What does "piccola privativa" mean (law)?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, translation

I can't find out precisely what "piccola privativa" means in Italian.

According to [Hoepli](http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/P/piccolo.aspx?query=piccolo),

> "*DIR* ***Piccola privativa***, diritto dell'inventore di sfruttare la propria invenzione mediante la sua realizzazione e la vendita dei relativi prodotti"

The same definition can be found in [Lo Zingarelli](http://dizionari.zanichelli.it/):

> ***privativa industriale, piccola privativa***, diritto dell'inventore di attuare, sfruttare commercialmente e alienare la propria invenzione

From these quotations, I can't see any difference between *privativa industriale* and *piccola privativa*, as I guess that both fit well for describing *intellectual property rights*.

But a few other sources (all found on [Google Books](https://www.google.com.ua/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22piccola%20privativa%22)) are confusing and embarrassing.

Bosco, "Lessico universale italiano":

> Sia i m. di utilità sia i m. e disegni ornamentali possono formare oggetto di brevetto quando hanno carattere di novità e costituiscono la cosiddetta piccola privativa.

Il Mondo:

> PICCOLA PRIVATIVA - Espressione giuridica che comprende tutte quelle invenzioni (la confezione di un prodotto, un congegno che migliora il funzionamento di un macchinario ecc.)

Rivista di diritto industriale:

> ... di rivendicazione, discendeva dalla soluzione di un problema di elementare ed assoluta semplicità che non implicava alcun apporto creativo anche sotto il profilo della mera innovazione, propria dell'ambito della ed. piccola privativa.

Finally, it can be found [here](http://files.einaudi-dirittoed-economia.webnode.it/200000019-4366c447c7/8%C2%B0%20lezione%20le%20creazioni%20dell-ingegno.pdf) that

> IL BREVETTO PUO’ ESSERE RILASCIATO
>   ANCHE PER INVENZIONI MINORI CHE
>   NON CREANO NUOVE MACCHINE O
>   STRUMENTI, MA SI LIMITANO A
>   MIGLIORARE QUELLE GIA’ ESISTENTI. SI PARLA IN QUESTO CASO DI PICCOLA
>   PRIVATIVA

So, in contrast to the first two sources, these four rather construe the "piccola privativa" as a specific intellectual property right for only minor inventions, which add up to some other, pre-existent inventions.

Please help me make it clear which of the two interpretations is correct.

Answer (score 2):

A short [wikipedia page](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privativa) informs us that:

... *Con le **privative**, assimilabili a diritti di esclusiva, si riconoscevano ad alcune classi di artefici particolari privilegi ... affinché essi non esportassero le loro conoscenze tecniche in altri luoghi, permettendo alla città o alla regione in questione di ottenere una supremazia tecnica e commerciale in alcuni settori di eccellenza* ...

So, at those times, if you were very good in doing something (i.e. jewels or dresses) you could be granted from a big city (i.e. Florence) the right to do it in a local monopoly if you agreed to do it only in that city.

You did not invent anything, but you had some special skills or did some improvements to a manufacturing process and thus your products would attract visitors and improve the city's business.

More recently the term **privativa** continued to have the meaning of an exclusive intellectual property right due to a patent and an invention, while **piccola privativa** indicated a right related to a minor modification of an invention (i.e. a different use or shape, an optimization of some components).

Nowadays, with the [Codice della proprietà industriale](https://www.uibm.gov.it/attachments/codice_proprieta_industriale.pdf) (2005), the term **piccola privativa** has been formally abandoned and the term **privativa** refers only to rights related to vegetable species.

In conclusion I would say that today **piccola privativa** is an obsolete term (at least from a legal view point) that does not refer to intellectual property rights related to a minor invention, but to the rights related to a minor modification of a patented invention.